# Creating an array that holds both integers and datetime C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create an array that looks like this when printed out:

```
[0]  100   10:00
[1]  60    10:04
```

I have created the array, I need to now add the values to the array:

```
int[,] ArrayOfSensors = new int[41,41];

/// <summary>
/// Generates Random Blood Pressure Systolic Value
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public int RandomBPSValue()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int RandomNumber = random.Next(90, 120);
    for (int runs = 1; runs < 41; runs = runs + 5)
    {
        ArrayOfSensors[runs, DateTime.Now] = RandomNumber;
    }
    return RandomNumber;
}
```

Comment: Um, why not just have an array of `ObjectThatPairsIntAndDateTime`?

Comment: a tuple might be a useful tool for you here.  Something like this: `Tuple<int,DateTime>`

Comment: `Tuple<int, DateTime>[] arrayOfSensors = new Tuple<int, DateTime>[41];` if you don't want to create a new type just for your readings. Otherwise yes, create some kind of type that holds both of your values and create an array of that type.

Comment: Maybe a Dictionary<int, DateTime>, I disagree tuples because you need to acess Item1, item2...

Comment: More like `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<DateTime, int>>`

Comment: Can someone do an example with my code above? I'm pretty new to c#. Thanks :)

Comment: just going to point out that you cannot use DateTime.Now as an index for your array.....now saying that, you can create a tuple, struct, class ect as everyone has pointed out to hold the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Tuple<int, DateTime>` for your code. Read the [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) here.

Your code will look somewhat similar to

```
var myComplexArray = new Tuple<int, DateTime>[5]; //array of 5 for example

Random random = new Random();
for (int runs = 0; runs < 5; runs++)
{
    int num = random.Next(90, 120); //use your real data here
    myComplexArray[runs] = new Tuple<int, DateTime>(num, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(runs));
}

//to show your desired output
for (var i = 0; i < myComplexArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] {1} {2}", i, myComplexArray[i].Item1, 
                                        myComplexArray[i].Item2.ToShortDateString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public class Observation
{
    public int Systolic { get; set; }
    public DateTime ObsTime { get; set;}
}

public List<Observation> RandomBPSValue()
{
    List<Observation> myList = new List<Observation>();

    Random random = new Random();
    int RandomNumber = random.Next(90, 120);
    for (int runs = 1; runs < 41; runs = runs + 5)
    {
        Observation observation = new Observation() { ObsTime = DateTime.Now, Systolic = runs};
        myList.Add(observation);
    }
    return myList;
}
```